# Use .so file in Windows JNI

Tags: c++

I want to use .so file in windows as shared library. Normally windows uses .dll file as library. But I don't know how to build my own DLL.

But I find a way to compile my .cpp to .so. In andriod app, it can load .so file as the library. Can any one tell me if it is possible to load .so in windows?

I found a way online. It is said that the function System.load() with absolute path can work. Actually, it doesn't work for me.

```
System.load("E:/XXX/libtest.so")
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A .so shared object is a library for use on a *nix platform. You cannot load them in Windows. You need to compile the source code to a Windows DLL, and load that.